# Java Unicode Issue on Windows

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, unicode, codepages

When I run my application within Netbeans everything works fine - I can read/write unicode texts and filenames, but when I run the jar by double click or with java -jar test.jar I only get strange symbols...

Is this a known issue? I use jdk 1.7 but build 1.6 byte code with it...

Thanks in advance for any help :D

EDIT: I'm not talking about stdout - the app reads and writes files and has a GUI

Comment: okay... I really don't like the solution, but if you run java with an extra argument - it works... (still not on double click, of course)

java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 test.jar

Comment: It's just a blind bet, but I guess somewhere in your code you read file/stream contents with assumption that the data is utf8-encoded, whereas JVM is using system's default encoding (latin1 in most cases).

Comment: I assume nothing at anytime, but when I run a java program containing System.getProperty("file.encoding") from netbeans, the result is UTF-8... when I run the same program from the commandline I get Cp1252... Whatever.. but java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar XY.jar solves it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run the application from terminal System.getProperty("file.encoding") outputs cp152,
but if I run it from Netbeans it results UTF-8.
this: java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar XY.jar
solves my problem, but I don't like the solution...